# How to use lists when attributes are magically created?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got a collection filled with models. The model has an protected attribute value, which is basically a number based on a few parameters. When the Model is loaded from the database the value property is null. On the first attempt to access it (`getValueAttribute()`) the value property is set, so the number is only random for every seperate instance of the model.

Now I'd like to get all values from the Collection. `$collection->lists('value','name')`... this returns an array like this: `['NameOfFirstValue' => null, '2ndname' => null]`. Which seems fair... because `lists()` apparently doesn't use my `getValueAttribute()` method.

But I still need that listed arrray, and can't seem to figure out how. Any thoughts?

**Edit:** I failed to mention that the collection is the result of a relationship.

Added my code:

My code:
Question model:

```
class Question extends Model{
... not relevant (?) ...
    public function questionVars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\QuestionVar');
    }
}
```

QuestionVar model:

```
class QuestionVar extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $value;
    protected $appends = ['value'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'question_id',
        'name',
        'min',
        'max',
        'decimals'
    ];


    /**
     * Returns the value of the QuestionVar when the 'value' property is accesed. Generates if not defined.
     *
     * @return float                Value
     */
    public function getValueAttribute()
    {
        if (!isset($this->value)) {
            $this->value = $this->generate();
        }

        return $this->value;
    }

... relation to Question, and some irrelevant stuff...
}
```

Question 1 has two QuestionVars: apples and grapes.

In my EventServiceProvider when I do this:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    Question::loaded(function ($question) {
         dump($question->questionVars->first()->value);
        dd($question->questionVars->lists('value','name'));
    });
}
```

I get the value of apples and then an array [apples => 5, grapes => null]. When I leave out the dump of the first value I get [apples => null, grapes => null].

*FYI*: I messed around a bit with the properties ($value & $appends) on QuestionVar, hoping to solve some stuff.

The loaded event on Question fires after everything is done. Leaving it out and doing this, would essentialy be the same:

```
$question = Question::find(1);
dd($question->questionVars->lists('value','key')
```

Comment: Using `lists()` on a Collection of models should call the accessors for those attributes. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `protected $value;` from your model and it should work.

Laravel's `getValueAttribute()` magic will only be called if you do NOT have a property called `$value` on your model.

I recommend reading through Laravel's `Model::__get()` magic method to better understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought I had tried that, but apparently not - or maybe in another git-branch. I will be looking into Eloquent Model a bit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove

```
protected $value;
```

`getValueAttribute()` only works if there isn't already a `$value` variable, so you are appending the `null` because `$value` is never set.

**EDIT**

Sorry Internet connection bugged out during post.